# Multi-sorting in underscore

Tags: javascript, sorting, underscore.js

I have Array object `ArrObject`

```
object = {
    Active: true, // type: boolean
    Code: '12345'   // type: string
}
```

I want to sort this array by `Active` field then `Code`. I need help to do that with `underscoreJs`.

**UPDATE**

My data:

```
data = [
{
    Code: "Code0",
    Description: "Description0",
    IsActive: true,
    id: 0
},
{
    Code: "Code1",
    Description: "Description1_edit",
    IsActive: true,
    id: 1
},
{
    Code: "Code5",
    Description: "Description5_edit",
    IsActive: false,
    id: 2
}]
```

Comment: You can use the [sortBy](http://underscorejs.org/#sortBy) function and pass in a iterator function.

Comment: What's wrong with using a normal JavaScript array `sort` call with an appropriate comparator function?

Comment: Sorry Jack, my mistake, it array, not list, so cannot use `sortBy`.

Comment: @mu is too short: maybe some old brower doesnot support it, I try to make it work in all browers

Comment: I've never heard of such a browser. And `_.sortBy` is just a combination of a Schwartzian Transform and a standard `Array#sort` call.

Comment: @mu is too short: I just want to ask how to to it by `underscoreJs`. And `sortBy` not work in my case.

Comment: What does your data really look like? Is it just a single object? You can't sort an object in JavaScript.

Comment: i update my question with my real data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd just use [`Array#sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) with a simple comparator function:

```
function cmp_bool(a, b) {
    return a == b ?  0
         : a      ? -1
         :          +1
}
function cmp_str(a, b) {
    return a == b ?  0
         : a <  b ? -1
         :          +1
}
function cmp(a, b) {
    return cmp_bool(a.IsActive, b.IsActive)
        || cmp_str( a.Code,     b.Code);
}
```

Then you could simply do this:

```
var sorted = data.sort(cmp);
```

If you need to be able to switch the `Code` sort order then you just need a reversed version of `cmp_str` (say `cmp_str_reverse`) and a version of `cmp` that uses `cmp_str_reverse` instead of `cmp_str`.

If you must use [`_.sortBy`](http://underscorejs.org/#sortBy) then you just need to come up with a value to sort by, something like this:

```
function combined(obj) {
    return (obj.IsActive ? 'a' : 'b')
         +  obj.Code;
}
var sorted = _(data).sortBy(combined);
```

The problem with this is that it is much harder to reverse the `Code` ordering. I suppose you could do a big mess of bit twiddling on the string's characters but that would just leave you wonder just what you were doing when you look at the code in six months. `_.sortBy` is a notational convenience, you don't have to force everything to fit whatever conveniences you have on hand.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/6tfcQ/9/

Comment: FYI - your fiddle no longer functions. Looks like its missing underscore library.

Comment: @TimothyC.Quinn Just updated it, thanks for the heads up.

Comment: "Much harder to reverse" - just tack on a `.reverse()`.

Comment: @Julian "Much hard to reverse *the `Code` ordering*". AFAIK I was thinking about changing the order of just `Code` while leaving the `IsActive` ordering as-is.

Answer (score 2):

The comparator can be based on the concatenated 2 fields like this

```
var sorted = _.sortBy(ListObject, function (o) {
    return o.Active.toString() + '_' + o.Code;
});
```

(Based on `"True" > "False" <=> true > false`)

Comment: Why would you want to sort by `"true_..."` and `"false_..."`? That seems like a bad idea. Converting the booleans to integers first might be a better idea.

Comment: @muistooshort Why it is bad?

Comment: I want it's sorted by value, `toString()` is not solution here.

Comment: @stiger Why? They are equivalent. "True" > "False" <=> true > false

Comment: I try to do it in common with all value type.

Comment: I want group by `Active`, item with `true` value will before `false` value. But in every group, I can change the way to sort `Code` by 'desc' or `asc`.

Comment: @Stiger If you want a very generic sorter, please check [TaffyDB](http://www.taffydb.com/). You can push the data to the TaffyDB and then query from TaffyDB using the sort() functionality built in. I don't think this kind of sorter is built in underscore.js.

Answer (score 1):

A little late, but maybe someone need this answer if underscore is really needed.

```
data = [
{
    Code: "Code0",
    Description: "Description0",
    IsActive: true,
    id: 0
},
{
    Code: "Code1",
    Description: "Description1_edit",
    IsActive: true,
    id: 1
},
{
    Code: "Code5",
    Description: "Description5_edit",
    IsActive: false,
    id: 2
}];

var sortedData = _(data).chain()
    .sortBy('Code')
  .sortBy(function(item){
        return item.IsActive ? 0 : 1;
    });

console.log(sortedData);
```

Check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/epgeroy/zmneu5r7/).

Answer (score 0):

Following [mu is to short](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18223234/286807)s answer, here is a utility function that can greatly simplify the use of `JavaScripts` [Array.prototype.sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort).

Comparator builder utility:

```
function comparator(){
    var spec=Array.from(arguments)
    return function(a, b){
        var v = 0, r
        for(var i in spec){
            r = spec[i]
            if(typeof r === 'string'){
                if(r.length>0 && r[0] === '~')
                    r = {key: r.substring(1), desc: true}
                else
                    r = {key: r}
                
            }
            if( (v=__c(r)) ) break
        }
        return v

        function __c(r){
            var va, vb, k = r.key
            if ((va=a[k]) !== (vb=b[k])){
                if(va === null || va === undefined) return r.null_top?-1:1
                if(vb === null || vb === undefined) return r.null_top?1:-1
                if (va===true) return r.desc?1:-1;
                if(va<vb) return r.desc?1:-1;
                return r.desc?-1:1;
            }
            return 0
        }
    }                
}
```

Usage:

```
var sorted = data.sort(comparator( {key: 'Code', desc: true, null_top: true}
                                 , {key: 'IsActive'}))
```

This will sort the data by Code (desc) and Is Active and null / undefined will be put at top (where default is bottom).

Here is a shorthand that this utility also supports:

```
var sorted = data.sort(comparator('~Code', 'IsActive'))
```

Where ~ signifies descending.

Here is a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cxz72jst/6/).